# Cells I input through ASP.NET web app wont Sum in SQL Server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

this is my query

```
UPDATE [mybookstore].[dbo].[volume_tab]
SET tot_vol = (sw_pp1+sw_pp2+stdwood+logs+palwood+hw_pp+firewood+biomass)
```

I attache a screen gram of the table after the query was run [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yFtp.jpg)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: What is the problem? What are you trying to do? Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have NULL values.   `5+NULL+25` equals `NULL` not `30`.

`IsNull()` will help here.

```
UPDATE [mybookstore].[dbo].[volume_tab]
SET tot_vol = (IsNull(sw_pp1,0)+IsNull(sw_pp2,0)+IsNull(stdwood,0)+IsNull(logs,0)+IsNull(palwood,0)+IsNull(hw_pp,0)+IsNull(firewood,0)+IsNull(biomass,0))
```

Comment: @ScottSmith Happy to help.